# Auto Fit Height of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have multiple tableviews in my ViewController and each tableview has different number of rows, please see image below:
[image]

Is there any way to match the height of the tableview according to its number of rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view controller, put code similar to the following:

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height;
}
```

Where `tableViewHeightConstraint` is an `@IBOutlet` to `NSLayoutConstraint`. Obviously with multiple table views you will need to reference multiple height constraints, so you'd just have one line in `updateViewConstraints` for each table view you want.

The advantage of this technique is that it takes all of the table view's content into account. It handles grouping, automatic cell height, etc.

Comment: I get nil value in tableView

Comment: The code above is an example. You have to adapt it to your particular situation. If you have three table views, you need to have three `@IBOutlet`s to those table views and three `@IBOutlet`s to three corresponding height constraints. Then you would say, `tableView1HeightConstraint.constant = tableView1.contentSize.height` and so on. The names of your variables will be different.

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine how many cells you have, then override

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return CGRectGetHeight(self.tableView.bounds) / self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)  
}
```

Btw, I suppose making use of header cells would be a better idea than implementing multiple tableviews.

Comment: I get this error: `warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
(lldb) `